# How to create a preview of another html page that is always 16:9

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm creating a really basic webpage editor where you can create "slides" which then can later be displayed somewhere else.

So in order to do that i've created the following page:

[image: my current page]

The left side is the preview and the right side is the editor where you can set certain properties of a paragraph. Basically both are

```css
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
padding: 2%;
```

Now i want the preview to always be in the ratio of 16:9 so it gives an accurate preview

This is my current code

```html
<div class="leftItem">
    <div class="leftArrow"></div>
    <div class="preview">
        <!-- Here is the text that gets edited -->
    </div>
    <div class="rightArrow"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.leftItem {
    height: 95%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.preview {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 40vh;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a padding bottom to a box *inside* the box you want to size. After that you will have to add content in a seperate child and position it absolute, as the new sized box will otherwise push all contents out. The important bit is this:

```
.preview:after {

  display: block;
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / 16 * 9);
  width: 100%;

}
```

It looks like this:

```css
.preview:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / 16 * 9);
  width: 100%;
}
.preview .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}


.leftItem {
  height: 95%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.preview {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="leftItem">
    <div class="leftArrow"></div>
    <div class="preview">
        <div class="content">
        <!-- Here is the text that gets edited -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightArrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you really helped me :)
Btw when i add a margin-top to a <p> in the content div now, the percentages wont work, how do i fix that?

Comment: @niehoelzz Percentages should work, but you should try and see if padding works or not - it might just be margin collapse thats causing this!

Comment: Oh okay got that to work. It was because margin and padding always compare to the width of a div...

Also how do i scale the div to be always 16:9 when the height is 100% (Not like in my question the width)

Comment: @niehoelzz I have not actually seen a way to do that apart from JS, to be honest.